# Trying to understand code in the PolygonSprite.java library file

Tags: libgdx, sprite, polygon

I am trying to execute this piece of code in my game.

```
public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha){
    PolygonRegion polyReg = new PolygonRegion(connectorTextureRegion, getVertices(), getTriangles());
    polygonSprite.setRegion(polyReg);
    polygonSprite.draw((PolygonSpriteBatch)batch);
}
```

In general, it works well but sometimes I'm getting an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception caused by the setRegion line. If I dive into the methods code, it fails at the first line in the for loop.

```
public void setRegion (PolygonRegion region) {
    this.region = region;

    float[] regionVertices = region.vertices;
    float[] textureCoords = region.textureCoords;

    if (vertices == null || regionVertices.length != vertices.length) vertices = new float[(regionVertices.length / 2) * 5];

    // Set the color and UVs in this sprite's vertices.
    float floatColor = color.toFloatBits();
    float[] vertices = this.vertices;
    for (int i = 0, v = 2, n = regionVertices.length; i < n; i += 2, v += 5) {
        vertices[v] = floatColor;
        vertices[v + 1] = textureCoords[i];
        vertices[v + 2] = textureCoords[i + 1];
    }

    dirty = true;
}
```

Now let me know if I'm wrong, but I feel like there might be an issue with the if condition. Why are we checking for this?

```
regionVertices.length != vertices.length
```

Whenever I get the exception, it's because the length of the region vertices array and the length of the sprite vertices array are equal.

Comment: Yes, at first glance, the purpose of the if condition seem strange to me too. Seems like, `vertices.length` is not supposed to be equal to `regionVertices.length`, and there should be `5 * (regionVertices.length) / 2) != vertices.length` instead. But maybe I'm missing something too, never worked with PolygonRegions. And just a note: why do you create new `PolygonRegion` in `draw()` method? If it's called every frame, that will lead to a memory leak.

Comment: @Arctic45 I need to draw part of a texture region that keeps changing everyframe. I don't see how else I could do it. Why would it cause a memory leak? PolygonRegion looks like a pretty simple class.

Comment: Looks like a bug. When I'm at a computer I'll look at the whole class to see. You're not creating memory leaks, but you're creating a lot of garbage, so you'll be triggering the GC, which will cause stutters. What about the texture region is continually changing?

Comment: Yes, @Tenfour04 is right, I misphrased.

Comment: I see, basically I'm just getting a filled arc of a circle, I'll implement an array of possible arc regions to reduce the amount of garbage created.